# Django checking user permission before the view

Tags: django

I have a user model as:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'pro_user'),
        (2, 'consumer'),
        (3, 'other'),
    )

    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default=3)
```

Now I want certain views to be only accessed by `pro_user` and `consumer`
and certain by `pro_user` only and certain by `consumer` and `other` and such combinations

I have seen `@user_passes_test` can be used for this. But for multiple condition how to use it

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda:u: u.user_type == 1,login_url='/page1/')
@user_passes_test(lambda:u: u.user_type == 2,login_url='/page3/')
def test(request):
    .....
```

I want to use this like

```
@login_required
@some_decorator(is_user_type1,is_user_type2)  #<-- pass list of user types allowed and for rest redirect to a url which shows "you are not authorized" 
def test(request):
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@permission_classes` decorator for this. It takes a list of permission classes as argument. You'll need to then create one permission class for each permission you want your view to have, like so:

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsCustomer(BasePermission):
   def has_permission(self, request, view):
      return request.user.user_type == 2
```

And then, in your view function:

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes

@permission_classes([IsCustomer])
def test(request):
   ...
```

Now, what this will do, is to respond unauthenticated users with a `401`. If you want to redirect them somewhere else, a middleware might do the job for you.

```py
class NonCustomerRedirectMiddleware:
   def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.user_type != 2:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
        return None
```

And then in your `settings.py` file:

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
   "your.middleware.folder.NonCustomerRedirectMiddleware"
]
```

Comment: but this is with DRF. Can I use this with normal views also

Answer (score 0):

I just took this from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/) and adjusted it slightly:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test

def user_is_customer_or_pro_user(user):
    return user.user_type in (1, 2)

def user_is_customer(user):
    return user.user_type == 2

def user_is_pro_user(user):
    return user.user_type == 1

@login_required
@user_passes_test(user_is_customer_or_pro_user)
def test(request):
    // ...
    pass
```

Comment: But i want to write only one function for each user_type checking and then use them. Like `@user_passes_test([user_is_customer,user_is_pro_user])` I mean i want to avoid writing `user_is_customer_or_pro_user`.

Comment: Have you thought about using Django groups and Django permissions instead? You'd have to change your User model for that though. In that case you could just create the desired permissions and check them with the `@permission_required` decorator.

Comment: which is better approach. Using groups or using some filter field. for creating fifferent user profiles